# MYSQL limit hosts matching with a domain name

Tags: mysql-workbench

In MySQL workbench I have an account setup for connections and I would like to limit connections.

I'm using dynu dns and have setup a domain like br1.mydomain.com which points to the ip of our office which in turn needs to connect to the db

Workbench lets me enter that in the section "Limit to hosts matching" but when I try to connect it's refused.

Comment: I'm wondering if enabling this option is not possible with a client that's got a dynamic changing public ip address. SSL is enabled and a good strong password is set so the extra question is it safe to remove the host filter for the account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, if the IP address changes dynamically you would have to update the user account constantly. However, it's possible to use wildcards for the host field. Still I would not rely on that as it might also give you some grief when adding more users and/or switching clients to connect from (e.g. a different ISP).

A much safer concept is to create an SSH tunnel and connect over that. Even for Windows there are free SSH servers available (*nix/macOS platforms already come with an SSH server).

Comment: I do use OpenVPN which is running on a computer at the office in bridged mode. Only problem is that the overhead is noticeable.